Obtaining the Runtime version of a function app via Azure Rest API
I need to pull the Runtime version of a Function app using APIs.

Calling https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2023-12-01
Does not appear to provide this information.
Calling https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions?api-version=2023-12-01
does not provide the information either.
Does anyone have any guidance on how I can pull this information?
TIA

You can get it using below rest api which gives the whole number with ~ as it stores that way in the configuration section :
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rgname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/funname/config/appsettings/list?api-version=2019-08-01

Got token for resource  https://management.azure.com/  and used as Bearer Token.
Output:

It stores the functions version as ~4 instead of 4.34.2.22820 or ~3 for 3.22.0.0 .


Is it possible to get the exact number?

This API will provide the exact value of the runtime.
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/host/default/properties/status?api-version=2022-03-01

Glad you are able to get it @john
